# Rounding digits exception

Tags: c#, teechart

If passing large number to SignificantDifference method

```
Steema.TeeChart.Utils.SignificantDifference(2011100616556782.7, 2011100616556782.7)
```

The following exception happened:

> rounding digits must be between 0 and 15 inclusive parameter name digits.

I got this error after a lot of zooming operations on large data.

Could you help in this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because arguments given to Utils.SignificantDifference exceed the precision range of [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28double_CSharpKeyword%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true).

Could you please explain how to reproduce the exact steps we should follow to reproduce the issue?

Comment: the arguments as mentioned above in the question. to reproduce the error , 
use
Steema.TeeChart.Utils.SignificantDifference(2011100616556782.7, 2011100616556782.7) as a standalone statement .

if(Steema.TeeChart.Utils.SignificantDifference(2011100616556782.7, 2011100616556782.7))
{

// do anything
}

Comment: @saif which TeeChart version are you using? I can not reproduce it here with the latest build available (4.1.2012.01310). Moreover, I understand that the issue could be reproduced with this code but we would need to know under which circumstances the issue occurs. Thanks in advance.